# How to create one consolidated SonarQube project for multiple modules of a C# project where each module built using NANT Build tool

Tags: c#, sonarqube, nant, multi-module

We are trying to setup a SonarQube analysis for one of your C# Project which has multiple modules inside it. Each module is built using NANT build tool.
We have followed https://arghya.xyz/articles/sample-nant-script-for-ci/ page to do the Sonar setup in each module's default.build file. Added sonarqube-begin and sonarqube-end targets in between the build target.
It worked fine but it was creating different sonar projects for each module but where as we need one consolidated Sonarqube project analysis from multiple modules.
Later we have tried something like having one common nant build file like all.build which in turn calls nant build files of all the modules. And added the sonarqube-begin and sonarqube-end tagrets in the all.build file.
With this approach the Jenkins build is failing with below error,

```
SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.6.2

Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild

Post-processing started.

The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.

Possible causes:

  1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps
  2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 14.0 and 15.0 are supported
  3. The begin, build and end steps have not all been launched from the same folder
  4. None of the analyzed projects have a valid ProjectGuid and you have not used a solution (.sln)
Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube analysis.
Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1

Could you help me how to resolve it or suggest other solution for this problem? Thank you in advance.
```